# How to do this in generics?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics

I am starting to use generics and been unable to really find the simple beginners guide to them yet so I am just doing trial and error.

I want to convert this

```
public void CreateTask(Task task, Student student)
{
            Task convertToUtcTime = task.ConvertToUtcTime(student);
            session.Save(convertToUtcTime);
}


public static Task ConvertToUtcTime(this Task task, Student student)
{
    if (student != null)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(student.TimeZoneId);
        task.DueDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(task.DueDate, info);
    }

    return task;
}
```

to be generic

I started trying this(I have no complied it yet so this might not even work)

```
  public void Create<T>(T entity, Student student)
    {
                T convertToUtcTime = entity.ConvertToUtcTime(student);
                session.Save(convertToUtcTime);
    }


  public static T ConvertToUtcTime(this T entity, Student student)
    {
        if (student != null)
        {
            TimeZoneInfo info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(student.TimeZoneId);
            entity.DueDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(entity.DueDate, info);
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

Now what confuses the heck out of me is how do I cast "entity" to a Task object but now only that but other objects that I need to convert like an Appointment that needs a timezone.

I just can't figure out how I could make it convert different timeszones for all my different objects.

**Edit 2**

```
// also used with nhibernate hence why everything is virtual
    public class Task :IEntity
{
    public virtual int TaskId { get; private set; }
    public virtual DateTime DueDate { get; set; }


    public virtual Task ConvertToUtcTime2(Student student)
    {
        DateTime s = DueDate ;
        // not use to returning "this" but seems only way how to get the object back.
        // I also realized I can do this as well 
        this.ConvertToUtcTime(Student); // So I am still using my extension method and no need to duplicate that code.
        return this;
    }
}

 public interface IEntity
    {
        IEntity ConvertToUtcTime2(Student student);
        // more methods/properties
    }

  public void Create<T>(T entity, Student student) where T: IEntity
        {
            entity.ConvertToUtcTime2(student);
        }

   // call generic method.
   nhibernateRepo.Create(task, student);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now what confuses the heck out of me is how do I cast "entity" to a Task object but now only that but other objects that I need to convert like an Appointment that needs a timezone.

You DO NOT need to cast if you are using generics. Or put this in another way: the reason you are using generics is because you do not want to cast. To illustrate this, below is an excerpt from [An Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of MSDN.

> Because the generic code does not force the boxing and unboxing of value types, or the down casting of reference types, performance is greatly improved.

In general, generics has the following benefits:

- improves performance
- enforces type-safety
- reusable

If you need a more specific example, look at (and compare) *ArrayList* and *List(T)* (search for them in MSDN). For the add method, *ArrayList* has the following signature:

`public virtual int Add(Object value)`

The same method of *List(T)* is defined as:

`public void Add(T item)`

Thus, you can see that a generic method takes in ANY type (reusable), and works on the type in a type-safe manner without the need to cast (improves performance). Of course, *ArrayList* is also reusable, but you need to do casting on it, making it less type-safe and has worse performance.

Having said that, my previous paragraph actually has a confusion. While you do can make use of generic to work on ANY type, you can also implement a constraint to have the generic parameter implementing a particular interface, thus limiting the generic parameter to a certain set of classes (those that implement the interface). A more in-depth look at the topic (Generic Constraints) can be found in An Introduction to C# Generics mentioned previously.

As for code sample, @Ed S. has actually showed a viable way. (Referring to the code sample of @Ed S.) Through the use of generic constraints, the parameter is thus limited to classes that implement *IEntity*, an interface of which has a *ConvertToUtcTime* method.

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to work through a common interface if you want to access properties or methods of the first parameter.  You don't want to be casting around inside of a generic method anyway.  If these entities derive from a common base class or implement a common interface you can use a generic constraint and work through them:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    IEntity ConvertToUtcTime(Student);
    // more methods/properties
}

public void CreateTask<T>(T entity, Student student) where T : IEntity
{
    T convertToUtcTime = entity.ConvertToUtcTime(student);
    session.Save(convertToUtcTime);
}
```

Comment: @Ed S. - Can you give more a more full example. First what is "where T: IEntity"? Second are you passing in different interface implementations or something? Like say one time I am passing in a Task how does ConverToUtcTime handle that? Then the next time I pass in an DateTime how does it handel that?

Comment: "where" is simply a restriction on the generic type. It means "I only want to allow types of T *where* T is an `IEntity`"

Comment: @Marlon - So if I want to pass in a Task into this method I cannot?

Comment: @chobo2: You can, but they need to implement a common interface (through inheritance or interface implementation, the later of which I showed above).  How else could the compiler know that the generic parameter has a method called `ConvertToUtcTime`?  If you have to perform a cast for each type of entity then it is not really a generic method.

Comment: Also I was using extensions methods so this seems to not be using them? But an interface instead?

Comment: You can't define an extension method on a generic type.  If that were allowed then you may as well just define an extension on `object`.

Comment: @Ed S. Ok I am still kinda confused. First time around I need to pass in a Task object(this needs to be passed in some how) plus the Student object. I then convert dates. Another time around I need to pass in a Appointment object plus the Student object. How do I pass it in so that it is still generic but I still can still have an extension that knows how to convert what I need to convert?

Comment: Task and Appointment *need to implement a common interface*.  The compiler needs to know what that the method you are calling exists somehow.  You can do this by inheriting from the same base class (or one from the other) or by implementing an interface.  I would suggest you spend some time reading about inheritance, interfaces, and polymorphism in C#.

Comment: @Ed S, isn't most of the linq library made up of extension methods defined on generic types?

Comment: @phoog: No. In the OP's example there is no constraint, so even if it worked, T could be anything, so it may as well be object. I think you are thinking about extensions to generic classes, i.e., IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: IEnumerable<T> is not a class, it is an interface.  It is also a generic type, upon which many extensions are defined. Therefore, the statement "you can't define an extension method on a generic type" is false.

Comment: @phoog: Right, I mistyped, but again you miss the point.  I said it wouldn't work (compile) because the method is generic, i.e., where does T come from?  Next, it **is the same as adding an extension method to object, so it is pointless**.  T can be anything, so it will be object.  Please read more carefully, and none of this helps the OP solve his problem, it's just pedantry.

Comment: I'm not trying to help the OP solve his problem, I am trying to correct an incorrect statement you made in so doing. Whether it's pointless or not, it is in fact possible to declare a method with the signature `public static T SomeExtension<T>(this T value)`. And I'd argue it's not necessarily pointless to do so.  You might want to, for example, if you are using an IOC framework.

Comment: @phoog: Reading through my comments I did say *"You can't define an extension method on a generic type."*.  Not sure why I wrote that, I know that I meant to tell him only that his syntax was wrong...